# Restler not requiring required properties

Tags: restler

I have this for my object class and API class.  I'm able to call post without sending a `task_list_id` or `display_order`.  As long as I just pass `title` it's calling the method.

```
class BaseTaskObj
{   
  /// @var int    $task_list_id   The SQL ident of the Task List to use for the Task. {@min 1}{@required true}
  public $task_list_id;
}

class PostTaskObj extends BaseTaskObj
{
  /// @var int    $assigned_id    The SQL ident of the Person who this task is assigned to {@min 1}{@required false}
  public $assigned_id;
}

class MyTaskAPI {
  /**
   * Creates a new Task associated with an existing task list.
   *
   * @param PostTaskObj $info The details of the Task object to create. {@required title, display_order}
   *
   * @status 201
   *
   * @return int The SQL ident of the newly created Task
   */
   function post(PostTaskObj $info) {
   }  
}
```

Comment: When you know the right syntax for doc comments, why you are not using them?

Comment: Because to the best of my knowledge I am using them.

Comment: See https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html also note that restler does not support `compound statements` as in example 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`task_list_id` and `assigned_id` currently do not have valid phpdoc comments. They do not have any assigned value as well. This makes them the required parameters for the api call.

But then you have `{@required title, display_order}` which overwrites the required list with invalid parameters thus making them not required

Comment: I'm sorry how do they not have comments?  I gave the type, the variable name, a description, etc...

Comment: To keep the question short I wasn't showing ALL properties in the example classes. I should have said that in the question.

Comment: Then make sure you edit what you post here as a working example for your case

Comment: Your comments are starting with `///` which is not a valid doc comment starter. See the link I gave in the comment for the question for valid syntax

Comment: So Restler is not accepting the single-line comment syntax that is shown on the link you provided me.  When I made it the multi-line version it started working properly.